# How can i fetch foreign key id directly instead of entire entity in case of lazy loading using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My Entity is as follows:-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "state")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
public class State implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer id;
private Country Country;
private String name;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "country", nullable = false)
@JsonManagedReference(value="country-state")
public Country getCountry() {
    return this.country;
}

public void setCountry(Country country) {
    this.country = country;
 }

}
```

In this entity instead of Entire country just i want to fetch foreign key id value...

For accessing foreign key (id) directly, is there any option in Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

You can also add (depending on you id column name):

```
@Column(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
private Long countryId;
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to add a dummy property to your entity and set it as `insertable = false, updatable = false`.

```
String countryKey;

@Column(name = "country",  insertable = false, updatable = false)
public String getCountryKey() {
    return this.countryKey;
}
```

Comment: It's working in java but giving an error when Entity is converted to JSON by FasterXML-Jackson with error message " Unable to convert into JSON"

Comment: That is another issue. Can't help as I haven't used that. May be you can try to add a dummy setter `setCountryKey()` as well ?

Comment: We already have setter    We are getting following error   error":"Internal Server Error","status":500,"exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException","message":"Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.test.myapp.domain.State[\"country\"]

Comment: You have to exclude the lazy-fetch collections from JSON serialization.